# Textbox data to Byte then sent to serialport & vice versa

Tags: c#

I am very new to C# and using VS, but need a little help.

I have a textbox where a user can put in a value, for example `"658"`. I want to `convert this into bytes first (max 3 bytes)` before sending it to the serialport. So the first byte sent is `0x02` and the second byte sent is`0x92`.

The second thing I am having issues with is the same but in reverse. I receive data in bytes, `for example "0x0B, 0xC7, 0x14"` and then I need to convert them into a decimal value and display them in a different Textbox.

I have tried a number of conversions that did not seem to work (parse, Tobyte and even using binary converter) so I am in need of help.

Thanks

Comment: can you show us what you have tried on your own.. have you tired a google search for `C# Convert Text into Bytes` I would start there.. then write something and come back when you have something to show where you are having issues.. `This is not a Code Factory Site`

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

**Convert From Numeric to Bytes:**

```
var textInput = "658";
// validate...
var numericInput = Convert.ToInt32(textInput);
var convertedToBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(numericInput);
// if your system is little endian (see below), reverse array output.
```

**Convert From Bytes to Numeric:**

```
// fourth octet is required to convert to an int32, which requires 4 bytes.
var bytesInput = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x0B, 0xC7, 0x14 }; 
// if your system is little endian (see below), reverse array.
var convertedFromBytes = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytesInput, 0);
```

Note, you want to pay attention to endian-ness.  See this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I get errors when I try and send the byte array through the serial port.'{
            txString = tbTX.Text;
            var numericInput = Convert.ToInt32(txString);
            var convertedToBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(numericInput);
            mySerialPort.Write(convertedToByte);
        }'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Encoding.GetBytes` and `Encoding.GetString` to convert `string` to `byte[]` and back.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, the conversion from ASCII to bytes seems to be working ok, but I think I now have the issues with the Encoding. From reading some other forums it seems that the Serial Port needs the right encoding first. What is the correct encoding to use?

Answer (score 0):

That should no be a problem as both the sending and the receiving serial port will accept/return a byte array. So the question comes down to how you create a by array from a string.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
```

The way back is:

```
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: Ok, the conversion from ASCII to bytes seems to be working ok, but I think I now have the issues with the Encoding. From reading some other forums it seems that the Serial Port  needs the right encoding first. What is the correct encoding to use?